# Ubuntu 18.04 live server: subiquity questions

Tags: system-installation

I'm playing with subiquity to automate the installation process and everything works well so far except two small things.
I relied a lot on the examples in the git of subiquity but those two questions find no answer. I hope so somebody will be able to turn on the light in my mind...
1- during the installation process, there is a screen asking if we want to install ubuntu, to install MAAS (region) or MAAS (pack). What is the entry to insert into answers.yaml to select "Install ubuntu" and skip that screen?
2- can somebody provide me an example on how to apply network config for two network interfaces in answers.yaml?

Thanks for your time and your help.

Comment: " 2- can somebody provide me an example on how to apply network config for two network interfaces in answers.yaml?" How do you set 1 nic? You probably need to copy that and indent it where the new indent is named "networks".

Comment: https://jaas.ai/u/maas-maintainers/maas-region/trusty/3 uses `juju deploy --config config.yaml maas-region`  so... that would make me believe it is not an option

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind but I don't have any network configuration yet in my answers.yaml, that's the point...

Comment: yaml for netplan uses this: https://netplan.io/examples Never used  subiquity but I hope they would use the same setup  ;)

Comment: The problem is I have no choice but to use subiquity. The server is not connected to dhcp and the installation process get stuck until I provide an network configuration...